# Words comparison in different phrases

Tags: database, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, information-extraction

Is there a way to tell if two words are the same in two different phrases? for instance "fat" is equal to "weight" in these two phrases,

```
I want to loose fat 
I want to loose weight
```

Comment: I oppose to your example, fat != weight, it's just your opinion, for your own opinion, develop your own algos

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward option is to query a thesaurus for every pair of words that might be equivalent. If all of your cases are like this, where there is just one word different between two sentences, that should be fairly doable. If you want to allow for sentences that are mostly the same but maybe have a few extra words, you could use a sequence alignment algorithm to give you a few candidate words to compare.

If your actual problem is significantly less rigidly structured than your example (i.e. you want to compare differently arranged sentences such as "I want to lose fat" and "losing weight is something that I want to do"), then you'll need to employ some sort of natural language processing approach. This will be substantially harder, but is definitely something that people have made progress on finding ways to do.